# Javadoc return made by concat of strings

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a function which returns a string made by the concat of more strings.
I'd like that Javadoc would automatically generate this information for this method, showing each part of the string.
Example:

```
public String myMethod()
  {
     return MyUtils.id + MyUtils.name
  }
```

Javadoc just says that the return is a String, but I want to show the "fields" as well, in this case id and name.

This is doable by hand, but this is not what I want since I need to automatize since the code involved in this approach is large.

Could you please suggest an approach to do that?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to do this except by doing it yourself.

Comment: IMHO javadoc should document **what** your method does, an not **how** it does it. But if you really want to expose the fact that you concatenate 2 strings, why don't you name your method `concatIdAndName` ? No javadoc needed.

Comment: Another option, if acceptable, is to include the source code in your javadoc, with the `-linksource` option of the javadoc tool